# css sub-menu hover issues in ie7

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7

Internet Explorer, our dear old enemy.... IE7 causing me headaches with my css drop down/fly out menu.

For some reason when hovering over a sub-menu that has a fly out level, that level flashes into view then vanishes immediately. Cannot figure it out.

http://cy4or.co.uk

Look at Services/Digital Forensics in IE7, you'll see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove position:relative from the list items for IE7:

```
@media, 
  { 
  #access .menu li { position: static;} 
  }
```

[position:relative triggers hasLayout](http://brunildo.org/test/IEWflm.html) and a stacking context in IE6/7, which combined with the float, causes the content to drop out of view.